# Angular 14 ngb-accordion not rendering through innerHtml

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, innerhtml

There are a handful of basic html pages in an app I'm working on in which I use a page-loader component to display the basic pages like this:

```
<div (click)="pageClicked($event)" class="page-loader-wrap">
  <div class="page-loader-slot center-width narrow" [innerHTML]="pageHtml">
  </div>
</div>
```

In one of the basic pages I am using `nab-accordion` and while the information inside the accordions is still rendering the accordions themselves are not.

This is what one of those accordions looks like in the basic page that is saved in the DB:

```
<ngb-accordion class="accordion controls accordion0">
    <ngb-panel>
      <ng-template ngbPanelTitle class="content">
        <div>What is a Single Case Agreement (SCA)?</div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbPanelContent class="content">
        <p>A SCA is a patient specific rate negotiated contract agreement between aJohns Hopkins entity and a
          non-participatinginsurance plan/payor.</p>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
  </ngb-accordion>
```

But once the page is rendered it looks like this:

```
<div>What is a Single Case Agreement (SCA)?</div>
<p>A SCA is a patient specific rate negotiated contract agreement between aJohns Hopkins entity and a non-participatinginsurance plan/payor.</p>
```

I assumed that most of that was being sanitized out by Angulars Dom Sanitizer so I made a pipe to handle this and tried:

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
```

```
<div (click)="pageClicked($event)" class="page-loader-wrap">
  <!--       [innerHTML]="pageHtml">-->
  <div class="page-loader-slot center-width narrow" [innerHTML]="pageHtml | safeHtml">

  </div>
</div>
```

But this actually made it much worse.

So what options do I have here? What can I do to render the `nub-accordions`? If that simply won't work what are some alternatives?